# Whats the difference between markers and dynamic markers in ace.js

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

What are the differences between the two?

```
addDynamicMarker(Object marker, Boolean inFront)
```

Adds a dynamic marker to the session.

---

```
addMarker(Range range, String clazz, Function | String type, Boolean inFront)
```

Adds a new marker to the given Range. If inFront is true, a front marker is defined, and the `changeFrontMarker` event fires; otherwise, the `changeBackMarker` event fires.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A marker is just a highlighted range.

A dynamic marker is [an object with update function](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/v1.2.8/lib/ace/search_highlight.js#L55) which can return custom HTML.
You can use it even to [highlight diffs](https://github.com/c9/core/blob/c5d3f33749439f90b4e3f40d18854f1fde31b13a/plugins/c9.ide.scm/diff/twoway.js#L469).